# Verify on a client workstation that all GPOs are enforced using OpenSCAP

Tags: openscap

I would like to verify that all my GPOs are enforced on client workstations using OpenSCAP. A manual verification of each policy is not acceptable.

I have exported my GPO's to an XML file but I can't find a way to load them in 
OpenSCAP or transform them into an OpenSCAP friendly input such as XCCDF or OVAL files.

Does anyone have an idea on how such thing could be done ?

My environment: Windows Server 2016 (DC) and Windows 10 (client).

Many thanks.

Comment: I can't help you with OpenSCAP, but why shouldn't they be applied (or what do you mean by enforced?) and can't you use RSOP/ gpresult?

Comment: There is no reason why they won't be enforced / applied. But I need to have some sort of way to proove it with a user-friendly manner : something that OpenSCAP does pretty well.